# Adding minimum point Z of polygon using ArcGIS Field Calculator?

Tags: arcmap, modelbuilder, field-calculator, python-parser, z-value

In the middle of a ModelBuilder tool I created, I have a Z enabled feature with multiple polygons. 
I want to add on a specific field of this feature, the lowest Z value of each polygon. I know this is easy to do using calculate geometry, but this option is not available on ModelBuilder and the "Add Z Information" tool is giving me error 00245 and the "Add surface information" is taking to long to process.

So I want to do this using a Python expression on the calculate field tool.

If this is possible, what expression can I use?

Comment: What have you tried?  Did you review the accessor functions for the Geometry type? The extent property looks promising...  You'll need to choose Python or VB to make this a single question.

Comment: I think python is better. I know that if you have a polyline and want to fill a field with the Z coordinate of the first vertex you can use the expression: !Shape.firstPoint.Z!. I was trying something similar, I thought that I could just type !Shape.minimumPoint.Z!, but it doesn't work. Other than that I have no idea how to develop this expression.

Comment: As stated, `Geometry.extent` returns an `Extent`, which has minimum/maximum properties.  This is a one-liner, very similar to what you already have.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, it is pretty simple. just needed to write !Z_Min! as the expression and it worked!

Comment: That extracts from a *field* named `Z_Min`, which may or may not correlate to the actual value in the geometry.

Comment: Yes, I just realized my mistake, sorry. Edit: how can I use Geometry.extent in this case. Extent(zmax)? It didn't work here.

Comment: Follow the [documentation](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/analyze/arcpy-classes/extent.htm) code samples -- ZMin is a property of the Extent object (`!Shape.extent.ZMin!`)

Comment: It works perfectly! Thanks for your patience.